# how to consume remote data on listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am consuming a web service so I added service reference to my application. 
I need to display the data on listBox. for this I only wrote the following code but its not working and I keep getting an error. My code is

```
public Antocids()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<Class1> p = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
         ServiceReference3.ProductsClient client = new ServiceReference3.ProductsClient();
        client.getProdDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getProdDetailsCompleted);
        client.getProdDetailsAsync();
    }
    private void client_getProdDetailsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Class1> p = e.Result; //here I'm getting the error

        listBox1.DataContext=p; 
    }
```

please tell me the exact procedure

Comment: Please add any error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your service reference does not return a result of type `ObservableCollection<Class1>`. In that case it makes no sense to treat it as such. What you should instead do is add the elements to an ObservableCollection when you receive your result:

```
ObservableCollection<Class1> p = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
public Antocids()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.DataContext=p; 

     ServiceReference3.ProductsClient client = new ServiceReference3.ProductsClient();
    client.getProdDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getProdDetailsCompleted);
    client.getProdDetailsAsync();
}
private void client_getProdDetailsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    p.Clear(); // assuming you want to clear the data each time you get a new result 
    foreach(var result in e.Result)
      p.Add(result) // assuming that e.Result holds an IEnumerable of Class1. 
}
```

If your service doesn't return some sort of collection of type Class1, then you will need to manually parse it into Class1 and then add it to the observable collection.

Comment: p.Add(result); //here error came the error is the best overloaded method add(.....)has some invalid arguments